# Jax-rs URI call

Tags: jax-rs, httpclient

I'm using HttpClient to access some api(Kubernetes) but I want to switch to jax-rs. Can the same functionality be achieved from Jax-rs? I was accessing the APIs in a java function. I'm a newbie to jax-rs and so far I know that it's use to create APIs.
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: You want to invoke http using jax-rs client APIs?

Comment: No, not through jax-rs APIs but through some jax-rs methods like we have in HttpClient

Comment: Example? I think what you said is same that I asked e.g jaxrsClient.get...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html is the package summary for the javax.ws.rs.client package.  with examples and directions below.  Basically,

1. use a ClientBuilder to get a Client (with heavyweight/common stuff
   like http/https parameters)
2. Create a WebTarget to denote an endpoint (including template placeholders)
3. Resolve that target (to get another WebTarget) with parameters
4. Invoke it to get and process the results (comes back in a Response object)